# custom sorting in a bindinglist of keyvaluepairs

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, bindinglist

I have a bindinglist of keyvaluepair filled dynamicaly.

```
  BindingList<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Homelist = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
  foreach (ListItem item in listBox2.Items)
    {
     Homelist.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(item.Id, item.Name));
    }
```

The list has key(id) and value(text) as shown

[image]

I want to sort the first 5 items asc and then the rest items also asc.the sorting must be by value and not by key.
example: if I have the values : 4,5,8,7,6,10,9,3,2,1,22 the sorting result must be 4,5,6,7,8  ,1,2,3,9,10,22.Any idea?

solved answer:

```
     public int Compare(KeyValuePair<int,string> a, KeyValuePair<int,string> b)
    {
        return a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value);
    }
 List<keyvaluepair><int,>> Playinglist = new List<keyvaluepair><int,>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
            {
                Playinglist.Add(Homelist[i]);
            }
            Playinglist.Sort(Compare);

            List<keyvaluepair><int,>> Benchlist = new List<keyvaluepair><int,>>();
            for (int i = 5; i < Homelist.Count(); i++)
            {
                Benchlist.Add(Homelist[i]);
            }
            Benchlist.Sort(Compare);

            //union 2 lists
            var unionedList = new List<keyvaluepair><int,>>();
            unionedList.AddRange(Playinglist.Union(Benchlist));

            Homelist.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < unionedList.Count(); i++)
            {
                Homelist.Insert(i, unionedList[i]);
            }
            game.GetHomelist = Homelist;
```

Comment: Um what makes it come out in the order it does now. If that's too intractable, chop the list into two. Sort them separately and then join them back togther.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Well no, you didn't answer any of my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea that Tony Hopkinson said is to chop the list into two. Sort them separately and then join them back togther.After that clear the bindlist and filled from the join list. Sorting can be applied only in List<> and not to the BindLists<>.The answere is in edited question